# Why WebAPI controller returns FileStream content instead of file but it works fine in MVC controller?

Tags: c#, file, model-view-controller

I am calling WebAPI controller method u sing jquery to show pdf content in browser but it displays me the stream content in string form instead of file. But when I use MVC controller for the same that shows me exact pdf file which I need to show.

Following code I am using to return pdf file:

MVC Method(works fine):

```
public FileResult FileResult()
    {
        string url = "http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf";
        string serverUrl = url;
        var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        var file = client.DownloadData(serverUrl);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
        MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        outputStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
        outputStream.Position = 0;
        return File(outputStream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

WebAPI Method(doesn't work):

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public FileResult GetFile(string FileName, string id)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + FileName);
            using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient())
            {
                ftpClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
                byte[] pdfBytes = ftpClient.DownloadData("http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf");// FetchFolderPathFrom + fileName);                
                MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
                return new FileStreamResult(outputStream, "application/pdf");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SaveError(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Expected Result:
Webapi should return file content instead of stream content.

Actual Result:
Webapi returns stream content which is being displayed as string content in browser

Comment: Have you tried using `return File(outputStream, "application/pdf");` instead of `FileStreamResult`? (Notice the lack of the new keyword)

Comment: File is not supported in webapi but its supported in mvc due to which mvc works fine I guess